# Create Custom Profile Provider using Entity Framework with my own database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-profiles, profile-provider

Up to now, I can create `Custom Membership Provider` and `Custom Role Provider`, but I have problem with `Custom Profile Provider`. After looking at some demo, I've found out that they use `web.config` to define the schema for the Profile. For example, in the tag `<profile>`:

```
<properties> 
<add name="AddressName"/> 
<add name="AddressStreet"/> 
<add name="AddressCity"/> 
<add name="AddressState"/> 
<add name="AddressZipCode"/> 
<add name="AddressCountry"/> 
</properties>
```

To access that field, they use `Profile.AddressName`, `Profile.AddressStreet`, etc...

My question is: is that the only way to define the profile schema? If I want to use my `UserProfile` table in my database, what should I do? I need the way to read I write the data.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why? So where do I store user's information?

Comment: I prefer separating User table and Profile table. In User table, I only store information related to security, such as Username, Password, Email, etc... Maybe your idea is different from mine. Anyway, do you know the answer for my question? :)

Comment: Yes, I know. But if I do that, what's the usage of custom profile provider?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not much of use to the original poster, but it looks like you can do as [described in this blog post](http://blog.ianchivers.com/2012/04/entity-framework-custom-profile.html). The gist is that you let the generated profile class inherit your own class which in turn inherits from `ProfileBase`, and finally override `ProfileProvider`:

```xml
    <profile inherits="Acme.MyApplication.ProfileCommon,MyApplication" defaultProvider="EfTableProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />        
        <add name="EfTableProfileProvider" type="Acme.MyApplication.EfTableProfileProvider,Facade" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/MyApplication"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>
```